# Powershell (v2) Path grave-accent (escape character) conflicting with Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, escaping, get-childitem

I have a friend with a video on my computer. The path is

```
C:\Users\Me\Videos\Tonys Videos\Dinosaur [1080p]\
```

In the Dinosaur movie folder is an "asset" folder, which contains a few .gif,.jpg and .png files. I wanted to learn a little bit about Powershell so I changed the directory with...

```
cd "C:\Users\Me\Videos\Tonys Videos\Dinosaur ``[1080p``]\assets"
```

The (`) was needed for the special bracket characters & the quotations for the space in the folder named "Tonys Videos". I can type in Get-ChildItem & the entire list will populate just fine, but I run into errors when I attempt to use the exclude flag (whether a single or multiple strings are "excluded" it still shows no output.

I ran another test, where I copied the "assets" folder to "Tonys Videos" (so the grave-accent would be omitted and everything ran just fine. I'm using PS v2.0 but that really shouldn't change much. My question is why didn't the "Get-ChildItem -exclude" work with the grave accents?

In response to the comment, this is my attempt with Get-ChildItem

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Me\Videos\Tonys Videos\Dinosaur ``[1080p``]\assets" -Exclude *.jpg,*png
```

I have tested this same format (as stated above) in the "Tonys Videos" folder and it worked just fine. Thanks for your continued assistance.

Comment: Show the code with exclude that you tried to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there are special keys in the path use `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "YourPath"`. With `-LiteralPath` you don't need the (`).
What do you write by the exclude?

For me this one works:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp\``[TEST``]\*.*" -Exclude *.jpg,*.png
```

You need the `\*.*` that you can exclude something. With `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath` you can't use `\*.*`.

Can you use this?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp\``[TEST``]" | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Name -notlike "*.jpg" -and $_.Name -notlike "*.png"}
```

Maybe an other user knows why the exclude don't work.

Comment: For exclude I used -exclude *.png,*.jpg
The literal path for some reason didn't take into account the -exclude flag (or -Exclude, tried both if it makes a difference)

Comment: I'll also add that `GCI -Path` option with `*.*` at the end does not include folders, that will only list files.

Comment: Pipe-lining the objects into a FilterScript did the trick. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can also include the string in single quotes which won't attempt to expand or interpret the strings contents. **Note** that variables won't expand either.